# How to disable startup and shutdown sound on Samsung Galaxy S?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, audio

Is there a way to disable the sounds on phone startup and shutdown? When I had JF3 firmware, there were no sounds, but now on JM1 the sounds are there :(

Comment: Btw, it seems that when I still had the old firmware, I somehow managed to use the way explained in the accepted answer unknowing that it had anything to do with startup/shutdown sounds. I just had forgotten what I did :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In System -> Sound and Display -> System volume
you can set it, unfortunately the power on/off sound is also tied to the touch feedback sound (ie you press a button, hear a sound). If that's not a problem, turn it all the way down and problem solved..

Comment: Oh yeah, this was just what I was looking after! I don't want any touch feedback sounds anyway! :) THX!

Comment: If you find this answer ***unuseful*** please downvote it

Answer (score 6):

Try [Silent Boot](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.antweb.silentboot) from the android market. It automatically mutes your phone when you shutdown.

Comment: But it doesnt work all the time.

Comment: Does not remove the shutdown sound.  The silent boot documentation mention it.

Answer (score 2):

In [this post](https://forums.androidcentral.com/showthread.php?t=194842&p=2111288&viewfull=1#post2111288) at Android Central, the suggestion is:

1. Open a root explorer, go to `/system/media/audio/ui`
2. Rename `PowerOn.ogg` to `PowerOn.ogg.disabled`, `PowerOff.ogg` to `PowerOff.ogg.disabled`

This requires root.

<sup>This seems promising, but in my HTC E9 phone (Android 5) these files don't exist :(</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Try SGS Tools from the market. It has the option to mute startup and shutdown sounds, or set custom ones.

Note: Works on a rooted device only.

Answer (score 0):

You can also just hit your volume key, and hit the settings button that shows up on the right. You can turn the system volume up and down from right there.